# Ionic 2 - Adding a background image to a page

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have just installed a new Ionic project - Ionic v2.0.0-beta.32

Im looking to add a background image to the home page of the fresh install, is there anyone that could show me how i go about this? All i can find is information for Ionic 1 and things seems quite different.

From what ive found, the image needs to be the following dimensions

```
2800px x 2800px
```

But apart from that i cant find any other tutorials.

This is my first Ionic project so be gentle

Thanks you guys

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The image can be any size.

go to `app/theme/app.core.scss` and add the following code

```
ion-content{
    background-image: url('img/background.jpg');
}
```

This is assuming that the name of your image file is `background.jpg` and is stored in `www/img/` folder.

Hope this helps

### UPDATE Ionic 3.x

Go to `app/app.scss` and add the following code

```
ion-content {
    background-image: url('assets/img/background.jpg');
}
```

This is assuming that the name of your image file is `background.jpg` and is stored in `assets/img` folder.

Comment: Worked for me with a slight modification `ion-content{
    background-image: url('../img/background.jpg');
}` This is because the compiled html file is in www/build while the image is in www/img

Comment: Care with relative path, for me works ../../assets/imgs/mymage.jpg

Answer (score 6):

For **Ionic V4** they use some new switch in the scss file.  This worked for me:

```
ion-content {
  --background: url('../../assets/Welcome-screen.png')  no-repeat 50% 10%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In ionic 2 the background image work only if you put the img folder into the build folder. If you go to inspect on the mage url it will show you that i finding for it in build/img/bg.jpg try to put folder img into build folder.

www/build/img

Comment: Your assets folder contains your images, and when your project is built, it gets moved to www/build/*. Not necessary to add it directly to www/build/img.